# search an nsarray for nearest values

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

i have a plist containing values as follows

1,23,45,67,88,99,34,26,50,28 - etc,etc

i am accessing the plist as follows:

```
NSString *path2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Fractions" ofType:@"plist"];
pickerData2 =[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path2];
selectorKeysFractions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[pickerData2 allKeys]];
```

now i want to search the plist for values near to a value inputted by the user

so for example if the user enters 69 in a text field i want to find the value 67 from the plist and read the key values for that dictionary item

how can i find the nearest value?

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your array is not sorted the easiest way would be to search through the array with a for loop and keep track of where the closet number is and what the difference was. Something like this.

```
int lowestIndex=0, lowestDiff=INT_MAX;
for(int i=0; i<selectorKeysFractions.count; i++)
{
      int current = [selectorKeysFractions objectAtIndex:i];
      int diff = abs(userInput - current);
      if(diff < lowestDiff)
      {
            lowestDiff = diff;
            lowestIndex = i;
      }
}
```

You will have to deal with the fact that the objects in your array won't be ints so you will need to convert them from whatever they are as well.

Also this method is not very efficient, if the array was sorted you could do a binary search which would be a much better approach.

Comment: hi ben  thanks for your suggestion above - assuming the array is sorted what would a binary search consist of?

Comment: Be warned, this can make your app SUPER slow if you have alot of values... (But it certainly is the easiest method to program!)